# Missing Landsat 8 Surface Reflectance Data From August 2017

Tags: google-earth-engine, error, landsat-8

I was downloading surface reflectance data from GEE from March 1st 2017 to October 31st 2017. I should be getting data every 16 days because of the nature of Landsat 8. However, there is no data in August 2017 and when I hit October, it started showing data from May 4th.

What's the reason for this?

```
// 定义经纬度坐标
var lon = 100.37183333333333;
var lat = 38.854350000000004;

// 定义日期范围
var startDate = '2017-03-01';
var endDate = '2017-10-31';

// 定义 Landsat 8 的影像集合
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
  .filterBounds(ee.Geometry.Point(lon, lat))
  .filterDate(startDate, endDate);

// 选择波段 1-7
var bands = ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B7'];

// 转换为 0-1 之间的地表反射率
var scaledCollection = collection.map(function(image) {
  return image.select(bands).divide(10000);
});

// 提取中心像元的地表反射率
var centerPixel = scaledCollection.map(function(image) {
  var value = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: ee.Geometry.Point(lon, lat),
    scale: 30
  });
  return ee.Feature(null, value);
});

// 获取影像的获取时间
var time = scaledCollection.map(function(image) {
  var date = image.date().format('YYYY-MM-dd');
  return ee.Feature(null, {'Date': date});
});

// 将结果导出为 CSV 文件
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: centerPixel,
  description: '2017',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

With the result:

[image]

Comment: Please include a minimal reproducible example

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq("WRS_PATH",133))
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq("WRS_ROW", 33))
  .filterDate("2017-03-01", "2017-10-31")
  .sort("system:time_start")
print(collection.aggregate_array("system:index")
```

The code above will show you two things

1. That you can use `.sort("system:time_start")` to have your collection sorted according by date. You can use this later also for your `centerPixel` feature collection so that the exported table is sorted. This solves your issue that "when I hit October, it started showing data from May 4th."
2. Indeed, there are no images for this collection in path/row 133/33 in August 2017:

[
"LC08_133033_20170310",
"LC08_133033_20170326",
"LC08_133033_20170411",
"LC08_133033_20170427",
"LC08_133033_20170513",
"LC08_133033_20170529",
"LC08_133033_20170614",
"LC08_133033_20170630",
"LC08_133033_20170716",
"LC08_133033_20170902",
"LC08_133033_20170918",
"LC08_133033_20171004",
"LC08_133033_20171020"
]

However.. if you use the [LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LC08_C02_T1_L2) collection instead, you get one image in August:

[
"LC08_133033_20170310",
"LC08_133033_20170326",
"LC08_133033_20170411",
"LC08_133033_20170427",
"LC08_133033_20170529",
"LC08_133033_20170614",
"LC08_133033_20170630",
"LC08_133033_20170716",
**"LC08_133033_20170817",**
"LC08_133033_20170902",
"LC08_133033_20170918",
"LC08_133033_20171004",
"LC08_133033_20171020"
]

There is actually another image in August 1st that is available in EarthExplorer*:

[image]

but note that it has the `L1GT` processing flag. According to the [Landsat documentation](https://www.usgs.gov/landsat-missions/landsat-levels-processing),

> All Landsat scenes are attempted to process to L1TP, using Ground Control Points (GCPs) and a digital elevation model (DEM).  In some cases (and more likely in older Landsat data), scene and/or sensor issues, or insufficient reference data can cause L1TP processing to fail. Scene issues include snow, ice, and clouds, which prevent an accurate registration of GCPs within a scene. Sensor issues include measurement/outliers in the spacecraft or instrument telemetry of an interval which also affect the usability of the GCPs. In these scenarios, a L1GT or a L1GS product will be created instead.

According to Google Earth Engine (see [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/help_missing_images#landsat)),

> Note that surface reflectance products are only generated for Landsat images with processing level L1TP.

Note that the image *is* available in the [LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T2](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LC08_C02_T2) level 1 tier 2 product, but not T1.