# Missing Landsat 8 Surface Reflectance Data

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-8

I was downloading surface reflectance data from GEE from March 1st 2017 to October 31st 2017. I should be getting data every 16 days because of the nature of Landsat 8. However, there is no data in August 2017 and when I hit October, it started showing data from May 4th.

What's the reason for this?

```
// 定义经纬度坐标
var lon = 100.37183333333333;
var lat = 38.854350000000004;

// 定义日期范围
var startDate = '2017-03-01';
var endDate = '2017-10-31';

// 定义 Landsat 8 的影像集合
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
  .filterBounds(ee.Geometry.Point(lon, lat))
  .filterDate(startDate, endDate);

// 选择波段 1-7
var bands = ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B7'];

// 转换为 0-1 之间的地表反射率
var scaledCollection = collection.map(function(image) {
  return image.select(bands).divide(10000);
});

// 提取中心像元的地表反射率
var centerPixel = scaledCollection.map(function(image) {
  var value = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: ee.Geometry.Point(lon, lat),
    scale: 30
  });
  return ee.Feature(null, value);
});

// 获取影像的获取时间
var time = scaledCollection.map(function(image) {
  var date = image.date().format('YYYY-MM-dd');
  return ee.Feature(null, {'Date': date});
});

// 将结果导出为 CSV 文件
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: centerPixel,
  description: '2017',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

with the result:

[image]

Comment: Please Edit closed Questions instead of reposting [Missing Landsat 8 Surface Reflectance Data From August 2017](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/468948/missing-landsat-8-surface-reflectance-data-from-august-2017)

Comment: This question should be closed, as the original question was edited with the above, so it's now a duplicate. I added an answer to the original one: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/469045/67301